# Django: Better debug messages for manage.py loaddata

Tags: django, debugging

I am trying to migrate a database from sqlite to postgres using `dumpdata`/`loaddata`. The problem is, if it fails, there are hardly any informations that are really usable for debugging - e.g. it just says `DataError: value too long for type character varying(100)`, so it's rather hard to tell which the afflicted data row for example is!

Is there any easy way to improve its error logging (at least)?

Comment: Look for models with a CharFields limited to 100 characters in your codebase and, potentially, change the max_length as a workaround to get the import running, if you can.

Comment: Well that's what I did, the problem is just that it is large project and there are about 30+ fields like that. Found it but then had the next problem with a 50 chars field... neverending story :(

Answer (score 3):

Try `loaddata` with the `-v4` option.  It has some pretty detailed debug data at the highest verbosity level, so hopefully that will help.

Comment: Well I hoped it does, but doesn't. In the first place it only let's me choose between 0 and 2 (`manage.py: error: option -v: invalid choice: '4' (choose from '0', '1', '2')`) and `2` doesn't give me any more information then before.. :(

Comment: My mistake - looks like it only goes up to 3, and that's only in Django 1.3.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that migrating from SQLite to full-fledged database like PostgreSQL can be tricky. So it might be a better idea to add another database to your Django project, using Postgres backend, and then copy the data using Django ORM.

Answer (score 0):

Kinda overdue answer but incase someone may use it.
I used this command. Replace with correct variable values on your end.

```
 python3 manage.py loaddata {your_json}.json --settings=settings -v 3
```